# can can i set up my parents to buy some application

Tags: 8.1, sync

My phone doesn't download whatapp,and other applications such as games I tried to make my account first,update my phone,email but the phone still doesn't download.it's say ask your parents to buy this applications.setting to windowsphone.com

Answer (score -2):

`what email you given at the very first time - that email id is called parent email id.
so just try with that email id once again, then it won't ask again parent email id.`

else do reset your phone settings->about->reset your phone

Comment: That's completely incorrect.